# Error: " cannot import name 'url_quote' from partially initialized module 'werkzeug.urls' "

Tags: python, flask

How to solve this error when run code ( Python Flask )?
error: File

```
"C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\urls.py", line 10, in <module>
    from werkzeug.urls import url_quote
ImportError: cannot import name 'url_quote' from partially initialized module 'werkzeug.urls' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\urls.py)
```

Gpgrade flask ??

And this is my versions:

Python 3.12.1.

Flask 3.0.0..

Werkzeug 3.0.1